# Crash with opencv video intitialisation

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg

I have the problem which is described [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/14257/peculiarity-with-videowriter-codec-selection/).

The extension i have already set correct.
What i have done regarding the suggestet Points on the link:

Point 1: I have looked in  my cmake file and ffmpeg, libavutil etc is all chosen.

Point 2: I thought all files are installed automatically in usr/src if you don't change it, isn't it?

Point 3: It is a new installation. But btw. how can i deinstall the lib?

Point 4: Shouldn't be the problem.

Thx in advance

Further infos:
Opensuse 12.3
Opencv-2.4.3
Qt4 Environment

C++ Commands used last:

```
VW.open(vsm, CV_FOURCC('F','L','V','1'), 25, vidImg.size(),!(vidImg.channels() == 1));
```

Filename in vsm: /home/Ingeborg/DA/videos/IMG-2013-11-19-22-3-5.avi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a flv or avi? These are two different formats. If you do a ffprobe on the file it will tell you the format. Also you need to check if you have compiled ffmpeg with the codec support for the codecs used in your file. ffmpeg -codecs ffmpeg -formats will help  you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. At last i have found libavcodec , which was missing. With ffmpeg installed manually i've got different other problems. I think the main thing is that i don't know how to install the stuff correctly on its place.

At the moment i have a similar problem and i think i found a solution. While installing OpenCV 2.4.7 i got this output :

```
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_world.so
c++: error: ../highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/__/__  /release/modules/highgui
/qrc_window_QT.cpp.o: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_world.so.2.4.7] Fehler 1
make[1]: *** [modules/world/CMakeFiles/opencv_world.dir/all] Fehler 2
make: *** [all] Fehler 2
```

I think the solution is [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/6732/missing-shared-library/). My simple question is (i feel a little mad, because it seems totally common), where i have to write the LD_LIBRARY_PATH down ?

Thanks!